# z3py solver.check() goes from "sat" to "unknown" when I increase length of Bitvector

Tags: python-3.x, z3, solver, bitvector

I want to factor a number n with Bitvectors in Z3. I use Bitvectores because I want to constrain single bits in p an q. This simple example does work and the solver returns "sat".

```
from z3 import *

Bits = 32

n = 12
p_vec = BitVec('p', Bits)
q_vec = BitVec('q', Bits)
n_vec = BitVecVal(n,Bits)

s = Solver()
s.add(p_vec * q_vec == n_vec)
s.add(p_vec > 1, q_vec > 1)
s.add(BVMulNoOverflow(p_vec,q_vec,False))

print (s.check())
```

But now I want to factor another number n with 4096 Bits. So I changend Bits=4096 in the example and used the same numbers. The solver give me now "unknow" instead of "sat".
It seems the solver discontinues at some point. Do I have to change some solver settings or is there an other approach to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your program with `Bits = 4096`, it does *not* say `unknown`. It simply does not finish quickly (I waited for a few minutes), and I wouldn't expect it to.

Bitvector solver is complete. That is, if you wait long enough, it'll eventually return `sat` or `unsat`, assuming you do not run out of memory (and patience). For this problem, however, the amount you'll wait might be practically infinite, and you'll most likely run out of memory on your computer long before that happens. So, I'm not sure how you're getting that `unknown`. Maybe you're using some timeout options, or something else you're not showing here.

You can try adding constraints of the form: `p_vec < n` and `q_vec < p_vec` to break symmetries. And it could indeed help in some cases since `n` is a constant. But this is in general futile, and for any reasonable bit size for use in cryptographic practice, the solver will practically loop forever.

Factorization is a hard problem for obvious reasons and an SMT solver is definitely *not* the right tool for it. See here for an earlier discussion: [Bitvector function Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702727/bitvector-function-z3/59708226#59708226)

Comment: Tank you for your answer. I know that Factorization  is hard. My problem i want to solve looks a little bit different. I got one bit of p or q for every posiotion in the vector and i have to find proper Bits to fill the missing ones, like 1101 = x1x * 1x0. I will try your suggestions. Do you know if this could work faster?

Comment: If you add constraints about individual bits, of course the problem will get simpler. But unless you put a constraint for the majority of the bits, (i.e., unless the unconstrained number of bits is < 20-30 perhaps), you'll run into complexity issues. This assumes your constraints are simple, i.e., they say the bit is `1` or `0`, and not anything complicated.